Does mod_proxy of lighttpd even supports X-LIGHTTPD-send-file?
I'm trying to respond with the special header "X-LIGHTTPD-send-file: /abc/my-file.dat" inside my Node server that is proxied through lighttpd. However the Content-length response by lighttpd is always 0.
Does mod_proxy of lighttpd even supports serving files through X-LIGHTTPD-send-file ?
I tried enabling sendfile like this :
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/api/" {
  proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", 
                             "port" => 80,
                             "allow-x-send-file" => "enable", 
                             "x-sendfile" => "enable"  ) )
}

I'm using lighttpd 1.4.74
The app runs under Express. Is it possible that Express doesnt send "X-..." headers to the proxy in the first place? How can I verify. If I send random header, they are forwarded by the proxy, but "X-Sendfile" and "X-LIGHTTPD-send-file" get stripped out without effect.
Thanks!

Use X-Sendfile as the name of the response header.

It doesn't work. It sends Content-Length: 0. No error in log. Only Content-Disposition is forwarded in the response. Thanks anyway!

Works for me, and I am the lighttpd developer who wrote that code.  Your terse and uninformative "It doesn't work" is a more apt as a description of your effort or ability to troubleshoot.  Note that lighttpd always strips out X-Sendfile before sending responses, so if you have a lighttpd instance proxy to another lighttpd instance which runs a CGI, then the front-end lighttpd (acting as proxy) will never see the X-Sendfile response from the CGI, but the backend lighttpd, if configured, will act on the X-Sendfile.

As an alternative, you can use https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_magnet with a few lines of custom lua code to process a custom X-MySendfile header from your backend.
